# Header gets cut off when I run a macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a header set up in a master spreadsheet in which I run different macros off of to sort the information differently. When I run the macros, the bottom portion of my header is cut off. My header does contain an image(not sure if this has anything to do with it). I also run the following prtion of code in all of the macros to format the first row of information:

```
Rows("1:1").WrapText = True
Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 55
Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 9
Rows("1:1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Rows("1:1").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
```

I think this may have something to do with the header getting cut off since i change the height of the row, but I am unsure how to approach this problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I figured out I just needed to set the margin in the macros. Problem solved.

Comment: Please write the solution in the asnwer and mark the question complete.

Comment: I just created my account and am unable to post in the answer box. And I just realized it actually wasn't fixed the way I wanted, can anyone help with the original question?

Comment: Did you set Sort method header as xlYes? Example `range.Sort(header:=xlYes)`

Comment: It deletes. Once I run the macro and go in to look at the header text, part of it is not there. And it still removes part of the header even when i set Header:=xlYes

Comment: How long are the original values? If more than 255 characters, that may have an impact.

Comment: Ok when I add the header:=xlYes, the header does not get deleted, but when I add in a recorded macro to reset the top margin, the header gets partially deleted.

Comment: It was the placement of my code. I needed to set the margin last by doing
   
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 90. 

Will someone post this as an answer as I can't yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Part of header text gets deleted when I run my macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699400/part-of-header-text-gets-deleted-when-i-run-my-macro)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. I had to remove

```
Header:=xlYes
```

and add

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `.WrapText = True` piece last.

Comment: @Harry, try putting `Rows("1:1").WrapText = False` then `Rows("1:1").WrapText = True` at the end of the code you provided, rather than the top. Does that help?

Comment: I just figured it out. I had to remove Header:=xlYes and add ActiveSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 90. I cannot post into answer boxes yet if someone would like to paste this into it, so the thread can be closed.