# Part of header text gets deleted when I run my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have macros that sort my master spreadsheet, but each time I run one part of the header text is deleted. I have no command specifying this action. I do run this line of code to resize my first row:

```
Rows("1:1").WrapText = True
Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 55
Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 9
Rows("1:1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Rows("1:1").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
```

I belive this may cause the delete but I am clueless on how to approch solving this problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Double posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16697709/698590). Please do not post your questions more than once.